# jquery-rails using jQueryUI with custom theme

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, jquery-ui, themes

I'm trying to load in a custom theme for a Rails 3.1.rc5 project to overrule the redmond one that is automatically included by jquery-rails. Can anyone advise me on this? As the redmond styles are always being included after my application.css and unfortunately the documentation doesn't give much away...

Thanks!

**Note: With jquery-rails it's pulling all the files in from the google CDN.**

Answer (score 3):

What I generally do is the following:

1. Use the jQuery-UI theme roller and download the results.
2. clean the jquery stuff out of public/javascripts. I generally leave the main jquery.js file there.
3. extract the images and stylesheet from the download and put them in public/stylesheets and public/stylesheets/images respectively.
4. rename the .css file to something nicer like jQuery-ui.min.js
5. extract the jquery ui .js file into public/javascripts/

when the dust settles I now see my theme in use at this point.

Comment: The issue is I'm not locally hosting the files but rather using the CDN, ideally it'd be good to know how to just turn of including the redmond css file!